# Heat Pump vs. Air Conditioning -- Especially in EVs

Tags: ac, heater, electric-vehicle

My understanding is that a heat pump (as a heat source) is essentially an "air conditioner running backwards" -- given that, and since air conditioning is an (almost) universal feature in modern cars, I'm wondering why some EVs (for example Chevy Bolts and VW ID.4 in the US) don't have heat pumps?

What has to be added to or modified in an air conditioning system so that it can also be used for heating?

What are the trade-offs that lead to cars like the Bolt with resistance heating and air conditioning?

Answer (score 1):

In theory, a heating-capable heatpump differs from a cooling only one only by the presence of a 4-way valve that switches the refrigerant direction. Thus, almost for free, you get 3x more efficient heating.

Then again, some caveats apply:

1. The comfort. A heatpump is slower to start heating, compared to a resistive heater.
2. The defrost cycle.  Are you ok with your heating system stopping once in a while in order to remove the ice buildup on the external radiator? Well, one can always add a resistive heater to switch to.
3. Both the efficiency and the max heating power go down when it gets colder, in contrast with the heat loss. In effect you need to carry more powerful heatpump all the time only for the worst case (it both costs more and is heavier).

Answer (score 0):

All heat pumps use the same refrigeration principles; pressurize a refrigerant creating heat along the way (expelled at the condenser coil in front of the radiator), release high pressure liquid refrigerant in a vacuum (evaporator coils inside the hvac box) to create cold air. Complicating air conditioning systems used as heat pumps; reverse the flow using a valve that is the heart of heat pumps to pressurize refrigerant in the hvac box for heat distribution in a vehicle. Electric resistance heating uses large amounts of battery power, affecting range. Heat pumps extract heat from the atmosphere, from the condenser coil absorbing atmospheric heat (even in freezing temperatures) and lose efficiency in cold temperatures. Tesla uses heat pumping in their ac systems for cooling and heating. Trade offs are made when designing heat pump systems. They're becoming popular and mandatory in some states for whole house central air cooling and heating around the country.

Comment: Given this, why would an EV designer choose to use a resistance heater rather than adding the components to the AC system to allow it to heat?

Comment: I am by no means qualified in refrigeration or a mechanical engineer. I do understand refrigeration with the term heat pump used to allow ac systems to run in reverse to allow heat into the interior of a vehicle or home central hvac in winter cold. Every vehicle hvac engineer must make the best decision based on up-to-date technology and adapt to vehicle designs; in this case, 100% electric vehicles. There are no right or wrong ways, just compromises like resistance heating. That's what's presented, no different from color choices, wheel design, engine power, automatic or manual xmission.